# Include one TeX file into another

Tags: external-files, input, syntax, texstudio

I have `main.tex` file with:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\begin{document}
\input{filename.tex}
\end{document}
```

Let say `filename.tex` have the following content:

```
\begin{abstract}
text    
\end{abstract}
```

Everything works, by TeXstudio IDE don't recognize any commands in `filename.tex`, because it doesn't have declaration of the document class. And so, it becomes inconvenient to work with this file.

Is there any better way to include files one into another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In texstudio, there's an menu `Options->Define Current Document as Master Document`. It makes life much easier for multiple file projects.

Comment: Here, thanks are in the form of upvotes and (if correct), accepting the answer. :)

Comment: In TeXstudio 2.12.22 that option doesn't exist; however `Options / Root Document` has `Detect Automatically` and `Set Current Document As Explicit Root` choices.